Is it normal that lme + random gives lower estimates than gls?
I was using a gls to model BMI trajectories based on intake of a nutrient, but realised I needed to switch to lme de to the multi-level clustering of my sample (twinID within famID).
The code for my gls was:
gls_21m <- long_data_m %>% filter(age>= ageT2_m) %>%    #filtering out cases for pre-nutrient BMI
  gls(BMI ~  ns(age,3) * ns(nutrient,2) + ns(age,3) * Sex + ns(age,3) * CSDS_weight_0m + ns(age,3) * CweeksDelivery
      + ns(age,3) * Cincome + ns(age,3) * MatQual + ns(age,3) * ethnicity + ns(age,3) * Ccigarettes + 
        ns(age,3) * diabetes + ns(age,3) * CBMI_mother + ns(age,3) * NSSEC3 + ns(age,3) * CIMD + 
        ns(age,3) * FeedingModality_3 + ns(age,3) * closest_BMI_T2 ,
      data=., 
      correlation = corCAR1(form = ~age|twinID),
      na.action = na.omit)


and my lme code is:
lme_21m <- long_data_m %>% filter(age>= ageT2_m) %>%    #filtering out cases for pre-nutrient BMI
  lme(BMI ~ ns(age,3) * ns(nutrient,2) + ns(age,3) * Sex + ns(age,3) * CSDS_weight_0m + ns(age,3) * CweeksDelivery
      + ns(age,3) * Cincome + ns(age,3) * MatQual + ns(age,3) * ethnicity + ns(age,3) * Ccigarettes + 
        ns(age,3) * diabetes + ns(age,3) * CBMI_mother + ns(age,3) * NSSEC3 + ns(age,3) * CIMD + 
        ns(age,3) * FeedingModality_3 + ns(age,3) * closest_BMI_T2 ,
      data=., 
      correlation = corCAR1(form = ~age|famID/twinID),
      na.action = na.omit,
      random = ~ 1|famID/twinID)
summary(lme_21m_adj_filt)

But the estimates generated by the lme model for BMI at each age (in months) are really different. For example, the estimates for BMI when intake of the nutrient is the mean level for the whole sample for gls is:
 age NUT_21m Estimate Std. Error   z Pr(>|z|)   S 2.5 % 97.5 %
  24    46.9     17.0     0.0575 297   <0.001 Inf  16.9   17.2
  36    46.9     16.1     0.0549 294   <0.001 Inf  16.0   16.2
  48    46.9     15.6     0.0578 270   <0.001 Inf  15.5   15.7
  60    46.9     15.4     0.0549 280   <0.001 Inf  15.3   15.5
  72    46.9     15.4     0.0579 267   <0.001 Inf  15.3   15.6
  84    46.9     15.7     0.0662 236   <0.001 Inf  15.5   15.8
  96    46.9     16.0     0.0718 222   <0.001 Inf  15.8   16.1
 108    46.9     16.4     0.0727 225   <0.001 Inf  16.2   16.5
 120    46.9     16.9     0.0702 240   <0.001 Inf  16.7   17.0
 132    46.9     17.4     0.0677 257   <0.001 Inf  17.3   17.5
 144    46.9     18.0     0.0699 258   <0.001 Inf  17.9   18.2
 156    46.9     18.7     0.0806 232   <0.001 Inf  18.5   18.8
 168    46.9     19.4     0.1000 194   <0.001 Inf  19.2   19.6
 180    46.9     20.1     0.1255 160   <0.001 Inf  19.8   20.3

but for lme is:
age NUT_21m Estimate Std. Error   z Pr(>|z|)   S 2.5 % 97.5 %
  24    46.9     15.8     0.0622 254   <0.001 Inf  15.7   15.9
  36    46.9     14.9     0.0594 251   <0.001 Inf  14.8   15.0
  48    46.9     14.4     0.0622 231   <0.001 Inf  14.3   14.5
  60    46.9     14.2     0.0605 235   <0.001 Inf  14.1   14.3
  72    46.9     14.2     0.0629 226   <0.001 Inf  14.1   14.4
  84    46.9     14.4     0.0696 207   <0.001 Inf  14.3   14.6
  96    46.9     14.8     0.0745 198   <0.001 Inf  14.6   14.9
 108    46.9     15.2     0.0756 200   <0.001 Inf  15.0   15.3
 120    46.9     15.7     0.0742 211   <0.001 Inf  15.5   15.8
 132    46.9     16.2     0.0725 224   <0.001 Inf  16.1   16.4
 144    46.9     16.8     0.0743 227   <0.001 Inf  16.7   17.0
 156    46.9     17.5     0.0825 212   <0.001 Inf  17.3   17.7
 168    46.9     18.2     0.0979 186   <0.001 Inf  18.0   18.4
 180    46.9     18.9     0.1189 159   <0.001 Inf  18.7   19.2

(estimates generated using the marginaleffects avg_predictions function)
I don't know if there's something wrong with the way I've set up the random part of my lme code?

could we have a [mcve] please ... ??

@BenBolker It was actually the avg_predictions function that was causing the error! I had incorrectly set up the counterfactual newdata argument, all sorted now!

Depending on whether you think the solution would be useful to others, you can either post an answer or close this question.
